# How can the invoice round off amount be shown in the purchase register report for only one of the invoice lines?

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2009

In the purchase register report, I'm displaying all the invoice lines.

I have included one column called `Roundoff` (invoice round off amount). This column is based on a display method. Currently the round off amount is displayed for each invoice line:

```
VocherId    InvoiceID  ItemCode  Roundoff TotValue 
VC-00001    INV-001    ITM-001   0.50     120.50 
VC-00001    INV-001    ITM-002   0.50     146.00 
VC-00001    INV-001    ITM-003   0.50     221.00 
VC-00002    INV-002    ITM-002   0.25     175.75 
VC-00002    INV-002    ITM-003   0.25     167.00
```

But it should only be displayed for one of the invoice lines like:

```
VocherId   Invoice ID  ItemCode Roundoff TotValue
VC-00001   INV-001     ITM-001  0.50     120.50
VC-00001   INV-001     ITM-002  0.00     146.00
VC-00001   INV-001     ITM-003  0.00     221.00
VC-00002   INV-002     ITM-002  0.25     175.75
VC-00002   INV-002     ITM-003  0.00     167.00
```

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

Add variables to report's `classDeclaration`:

```
real roundOff; 
VendInvoiceAccount currentInvoiceId;
```

Add display method to the section where the roundoff column is located:

```
display real getRoundOff()
{
    return roundOff;
}
```

Set `DataMethod` property of the field to `getRoundOff`.

And override `executeSection` for this section:

```
public void executeSection()
{
    if (purchLine.InvoiceAccount == currentInvoiceId) 
    {
        roundOff = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        roundOff = purchLine.RoundOff;
        currentInvoiceId == purchLine.InvoiceAccount;
    }
    super();
```

}

Comment: i want to show the value for one random line and show zero for the remaining lines for the same invoiceId.

Comment: I have edited the answer so that only the first line displays roundoff. Note that `purchLine.InvoiceAccount` does not exist. Use the corresponding filed. I can't figure out why would you need a random line display a round-off amount?